# How to strict Shapes Circle based on the value of a cell?

Tags: vba

I wanted to restrict the Shapes after and before based on the cell value.
for example: If Cell A2 value <> "No" then do the below code:

```
 With ActiveSheet
      .ClearCircles 
     ShapesBefore = .Shapes.Count 
     .CircleInvalid 'circle invalid
     ShapesAfter = .Shapes.Count 
'if shapes after > shapes before request a fix and exit sub
     If ShapesAfter > ShapesBefore Then
          MsgBox ("You have invalid circled entries")
                 End
               End If
          End With
```

is it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `If` clause

```
    With ActiveSheet
        If .Cells(2, 1).Value <> "No" Then
            .ClearCircles
            ShapesBefore = .Shapes.Count
            .CircleInvalid 'circle invalid
            ShapesAfter = .Shapes.Count
            'if shapes after > shapes before request a fix and exit sub
            If ShapesAfter > ShapesBefore Then
                MsgBox ("You have invalid circled entries")
                End
            End If
        End If
    End With
```